# how can I extract info from a list of articles?

Tags: python, nlp, openai-api

I have a list of recommendations on the stock market. Typically, one of the recommendations could be: « analyst X confirms his positive bias on the stock Y with a price target Z »

I want to have ultimately a database containing:

```
reco url | reco date | analyst X | stock Y | price target Z
```

The recommendation will always differ slightly in format and wording, but the info is always more or less the same.

Copilot (chatGPT) sydney package in python works just fine. But only problem is there is a limit for the number of queries which is hit pretty quickly.

I’ve searched for alternatives such as Spacy package, but not too sure how to use it for this use case.